# SQL Oracle group function problems

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have problems understanding how to group with multiple tables, if i were to have a single table i can make it work, but not with two this is my problem bellow:

```
SELECT oc.custID, oc.custfirstname, oc.tankcap, oc.housetype, 
MIN(AVG(oh.fall)) FROM oil_cust oc, oil_houset oh GROUP BY oh.fall;
```

And this is the output that i get:

```
SELECT oc.custID, oc.custfirstname, oc.tankcap, oc.housetype,
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

I tried to have another group function for both tables but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Hi, you have a Cartesian join here, there is nothing to link the two tables together. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping by the column that you are aggregating on -- the exact opposite of what you should be doing.

Comment: Not only that but they are also nesting aggregate functions and unless my memory is failing me, that it not allowed in any RDBMS.

Comment: Actually you can as long as you do not have other non-aggregate columns. The group by applies to the inner function, and the outer function then executes without a group by so you can calculate the average of departmental salary maxima, for example. In this case if the minimum average "fall" was required then the group by can stay but the other non-aggregate columns would have to go.

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. I guess I will have to perform some testing on it.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @DavidAldridge That (the nesting of aggregate functions) is non ISO/ANSI, right? I haven't seen it before and I couldn't make it work in Postgres or SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube No idea ... It might be ANSI and not supported by others, or non-ANSI and the same.